# Installing node with homebrew problems mac OS

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

after installing homebrew,

after running `brew install node`

I test with:

```
node --version
```

I get:

> command not found

If I rerun the install command:
I get:

> MacBook-Pro:~ evanloiterman$ brew install node Warning: node 10.9.0 is
>   already installed, it's just not linked You can use `brew link node`
>   to link this version. MacBook-Pro:~ evanloiterman$ brew link node
>   Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.9.0...  Error: Could not symlink
>   include/node/common.gypi Target /usr/local/include/node/common.gypi
>   already exists. You may want to remove it:   rm
>   '/usr/local/include/node/common.gypi'

I try `brew link node`

I get:

> Error: Could not symlink include/node/common.gypi Target
>   /usr/local/include/node/common.gypi already exists. You may want to
>   remove it:   rm '/usr/local/include/node/common.gypi'
>
> To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:   brew link
>   --overwrite node
>
> To list all files that would be deleted:   brew link --overwrite
>   --dry-run node

What should I try next to ensure this is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install NVM (Node Version Manager). With this tool you can choose which node to use and install.

https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-node-js-tutorial-using-nvm-on-mac-os-x-and-ubuntu/

Comment: prior to doing this should I uninstall node I attempted to install with homebrew?

Comment: @namretiolnave sorry did some research, you should remove old node before install with nvm

Comment: hmm I thought I uninstalled node -I'll review my steps and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/*
```

then:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/include/node
brew unlink node
brew link node
```

Maybe this issue it's similar to this [brew link solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57984026/why-does-brew-say-that-nodejs-is-installed#57985243)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run Homebrew UNINSTALL node and begin clean.

To fix this problem I found the answer on this site:

[uninstall homebrew on a mac](http://osxdaily.com/2018/08/12/how-uninstall-homebrew-mac/)

I ran the ruby script and then decided to just start clean again and forget about homebrew for now.