# Why does brew say that nodejs is installed?

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

First of all, I run `node` in macOS terminal, and get

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

I run `brew install node` and get

`` Warning: node 12.10.0 is already installed, it's just not linked You can use `brew link node` to link this version. ``

So I run `brew link node` and get

```
Error: Could not symlink include/node/common.gypi                                                                 
/usr/local/include/node is not writable.
```

I suppose that's some permission issue. So I run it with sudo and get

```
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.                                   
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all                                      
build scripts full access to your system.
```

Then I try `brew uninstall node`, and repeat all the above steps, and still get the same errors. What do I do?

Comment: A: because it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Doing `brew link --overwrite node` worked.

Answer (score 10):

**Note**: Never use `sudo` with `brew`. Running `brew` as `root` may change the owner of brew related files, and make it inaccessible by current user.

Answer for the question: you may have broken the permission of `/usr/local/include/node` directory already by using `sudo`. To fix this,

```sh
rm -rf /usr/local/include/node
brew unlink node
brew link node
```

If the above commands don't fix your problem. Try to fix all folder permission under `/usr/local` recursively. Then try the above fix again.

```sh
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/*
```

Comment: upon doing ```brew unlink node``` I get ```Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node  ```.  Same error when I run ```brew link node```. When I run the last command I get ```chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted```

Comment: @zengod `chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted` is okay, the owner of the folder itself is not permitted to be changed. But the owners of sub-folders have been changed. This should have fixed the `Running Homebrew as root` warning. Can you provide more detail in your post? What's the output of `brew doctor`, `brew info node`? And does the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28225045/5101148) for "Error: No such keg" work for you?